# Get custom taxonomy's custom meta from outside the loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created a number of custom fields for custom taxonomy. Got no problem pulling their values inside the query. But in this case, I get them repeating as many times as I have posts in this taxonomy.

This is the code with it inside the loop

```
$tables_terms = $atts['custom'];

$tabargs = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'offset'         => 0,   
    'post_type'      => 'customtables',
    'tax_query'     => array(
          array(
            'taxonomy' => 'tables', 
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 
                $tables_terms
            )
          )
        )
);

$tabs = new WP_Query( $tabargs );


if( $tabs->have_posts() ){
    while( $tabs->have_posts() ) : $tabs->the_post();
        $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'tables' );
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $t_id = $term->term_id;
            $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$t_id" );
            echo $term_meta['term_1'];
        }   
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    echo $custom;
}
```

How do I get these to show once, outside the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the following code actually worked for me

```
$term_slug = $tables_terms;
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies();
foreach ( $taxonomies as $tax_type_key => $taxonomy ) {
    if ( $term_object = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug , $taxonomy ) ) {
        break;
    }
}
$t_id = $term_object->term_id;
$term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$t_id" );
```

and from there on, I simply echoed each meta like this

```
echo $term_meta['term_1'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use, [get_term_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_meta/);

get_term_meta retrieves metadata for a term.

`get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'your_term_name', true )`

Comment: I tried it right after $tabs = new WP_Query( $tabargs ); then inside if( $tabs->have_posts() ){, then inside while( $tabs->have_posts() ) : $tabs->the_post();, and then inside foreach. Though, inside the last 2 it would still show up twice- i think. In any case, it didn't work in any of these

Answer (score 0):

### Try Like that:

## Store your output in a array and check when store it that value already exist or not.

```
$tables_terms = $atts['custom'];

$tabargs = array(
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'offset'         => 0,   
'post_type'      => 'customtables',
'tax_query'     => array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'tables', 
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => array( 
            $tables_terms
        )
      )
    )
    );

  $tabs = new WP_Query( $tabargs );

  $term_meta_array = array();
  if( $tabs->have_posts() ){
  while( $tabs->have_posts() ) : $tabs->the_post();
    $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'tables' );

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $t_id = $term->term_id;
        $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_$t_id" );
        echo $term_meta['term_1'];
        if(!in_array($term_meta['term_1'], $term_meta_array)) array_push($$term_meta_array, $term_meta['term_1']);
    }   
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata();
  echo $custom;
  foreach($term_meta_array as $st){
  echo $st;
}
}
```

Comment: already made it work (see my own answer above), Thanks, though!